# Energy in dynamical variational principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, variational-principle

In quantum mechanics we use variational principle in order to find approximate expression for the ground state. Lets assume our probe wavefunction $|\Psi\rangle$ can be expanded in orthonormal basis 
$$|\Psi\rangle = \sum\limits_{n}f_n |n\rangle$$
Variational ansatz dictates minimization of the energy functional
$$E[f_n,f_n^*] = \langle\Psi|\hat{H}|\Psi\rangle$$
with constraint $\langle \Psi|\Psi\rangle=1$ ($f_n^*$ is a complex conjugate). Taking derivative we have equations for the coefficients:
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial f_n^*} = 0.$$

There is also dynamical variational principle where one minimizes Schrodinger action
$$S = \int dt \mathcal{L}$$
where
$$\mathcal{L} = \langle\Psi(t)|i\hbar\partial_t - \hat{H}|\Psi(t)\rangle$$
Using Euler-Lagrange equations we get differential equations for $f_{n}$:
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial f_n^*} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{f}_n^*}=0$$
My question is whether or not energy $E(t) = \langle\Psi(t)|\hat{H}|\Psi(t)\rangle$ defined with coefficients $f_n(t)$ derived from Euler-Lagrange equations is a conserved quantity i.e. $d E(t)/dt = 0$?

What I have in mind is the Bose-Hubbard Hamiltonian
$$\hat{H} = -J\sum\limits_{<i,j>}\hat{a}_i^{\dagger}\hat{a}_j + \frac{U}{2}\sum\limits_i\hat{n}_i(\hat{n}_i-1)-\mu\sum\limits_{i}\hat{n}_i$$
with variational ansatz:
$$|\Psi\rangle = \bigotimes\limits_{i}|\psi_i\rangle,\ \ |\psi_i\rangle = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{n_F}f_{n}^{(i)}|n\rangle_{i}$$
In this case Coefficients $f_n$ are not a solution of the Schrodinger equation $i\hbar \partial_t |\Psi\rangle = \hat{H} |\Psi\rangle$.

Comment: Sorry, removed my comments, I understand the issue now. For consistency, you should also write $\lvert \Psi (t)\rangle$ in the line where you have $\mathcal{L} = $ to emphasize the variational principle already gives a time-dependent state.

Comment: The reason I am curious about that is the imaginary-time method for obtaining ground state of the system. If you change variables $\tau = it$ and propagate the equation step by step in small intervals $\Delta\tau$ (you should normalize wavefunction after each step) than you should end up with the ground state ideally when $\tau \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Certainly, $E(f_n, f_n^*)$ is the Hamiltonian of the mechanical system defined by the (time independent) Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(f_n, f_n^*, \dot{f}_n, \dot{f}_n^*)$. Thus it conserved. Please see my answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/197297/how-to-include-berry-connection-in-hamiltonian/197828#197828, where you can think of the parameter vector $R$ as the set of coefficients $f_n, f_n*$. Technically, the conservation stems from the antisymmetry of the Berry curvature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @David! I also wonder what happens to the energy when you replace real time $t$ with imaginary time $\tau = it$. Can we say that it is always diminishing $dE(\tau)/d\tau < 0$ or not?

Comment: If the trial wave function manifold is close enough to the ground state, then the conserved energy value on the classical solution is a good approximation of the ground state energy. (Quantum) corrections to this first approximation can be obtained from quantizing the effective theory defined by the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$.  Since the manifold of trial wave functions is in general non-Euclidean, one needs more general quantization techniques than canonical quantization to perform this task (e.g. geometric quantization).  …

Comment: The main reason for the existence of this correction is that, while classically, all the states on the classical solution path in the trial wave function manifold are degenerate in energy, quantum mechanically there should be a unique ground state, which is obtained from quantum splitting of this degeneracy.  The computation of the correction to the ground energy, indeed involves imaginary time replacement. …

Comment: This method is called instanton calculus. It is really not trivial to implement and requires special expertise, but it led to tremendously important discoveries in physics. The article given at the end of this note is my favorite reference doing instanton calculus on geometrical manifolds of the type obtained in the variational approach. However, it treats a much simpler problem (a single spin) than the Bose-Hubbard model. I'll try to write for you a more comprehensive answer (with more references) in the next few weeks if I can.  
http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0111139v1

Comment: I have never heard about instanton calculus. Something new to me. I am waiting for your final answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you take the equation of motion on the Schrodinger Field Action, you are simple imposing this equation:
$$
\left.\frac{\delta S}{\delta f_{n}}\right|_{Bulk}=0\,\,\,\,\rightarrow \,\,\,\,\, H_{n}^{m} f_m=i\hbar\frac{df_n (t)}{dt}
$$

Note that I used the word Bulk below the functional derivative. This is because, functional derivative acts only in the interior of the functional, and don't tells you how the boundary terms behaves. In this problem the boundary term are related to the initial state of the system. This is what you want to find. The initial state that you want to find is precisely the state that conserves the probabilities:
$$
\frac{d(f^{*}_{n}f^{n})}{dt}(t)=0
$$

So, the answer that the variation inside the Bulk of the action give us is that if you want such state you need try to diagonalize $H_{mn}$. Very trivial answer. Actually what you want more is the lowest eigenvalue of $H$, so you already know that. The answer for your question is that the equation of motion is not necessary to specify your state. The equation of motion only tells you how some state evolutes through time.

If you are interested in functional applications to vacuum state you can use the idea that in the limit $T\rightarrow 0$ of a system in thermal equilibrium with a reservoir the density matrix get close to the ground state:

$$
\rho=\frac{e^{-\beta H}}{tr(e^{-\beta H})}\,\,\,\,\rightarrow \,\,\,\,|0\rangle\langle 0|
$$

And then you can use the [path integral ideas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) seeing the $\beta$ as a time, and the limit as a $\beta\rightarrow \infty$.